# Clickhouse Year & Month - Array function

Tags: clickhouse

I am having a datetime range say '2020-06-24 23:00:00' and '2022-10-12 23:59:59'. My task is to create sequence of records with the lastdateofmonth between these 2 dates. For this, I tried to use the following query (I am using ClickHouse - WITH FILL does not work in my version):

```
SELECT id,
        start_date,
        mod_end_date,
        mod_end_month,
        arrayJoin(arr_year_no)  as sep_year,
        if(arrayJoin(arr_month_no) % 12 = 0,12, arrayJoin(arr_month_no) % 12)
                              as sep_month
from
(
    select id, 
        startdatetime                        as start_date,
        enddatetime                          as end_date,
       if(toDate(enddatetime) < toDate('2022-10-12 23:59:59'),      -- Input 2
                ifNull(toDateTime(enddatetime), today()),
                        toDateTime('2022-10-12 23:59:59'))  -- Input 2
                                             as mod_end_date,
        toMonth(mod_end_date)                as mod_end_month,
        toYear(mod_end_date)                 as mod_end_year,
        range(
                toUInt32(toYear(ifNull(start_date, today()))),
                toUInt32(mod_end_year + 1))  as arr_year_no,
        range(
                toUInt32(toMonth(ifNull(start_date, today()))),
                toUInt32(date_diff(month,start_date, mod_end_date) + 1)) as arr_month_no
    from table1
    WHERE toDate(startdatetime) between toDate('2020-06-24 23:00:00') -- Input 1
        AND toDate('2022-10-12 23:59:59')                          -- Input 2
        AND id = 1307
) tbl1
```

But this is creating union of sep_year and sep_month fields; for 2020, all the sep_month will be returned followed by 2021 and 2022. But I want calendar dates but not all combinations of sep_year and sep_month.
I am receiving the following outcomes -

| id | start_date | end_date | mod_end_month | sep_year | sep_month | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1307 | 2020-06-24 23:00:00 | 2022-10-12 22:59:59 | 10 | 2020 | 7 |  |
| 1307 | 2020-06-24 23:00:00 | 2022-10-12 22:59:59 | 10 | 2020 | 8 |  |
| 1307 | 2020-06-24 23:00:00 | 2022-10-12 22:59:59 | 10 | 2020 | 9 |  |
| 1307 | 2020-06-24 23:00:00 | 2022-10-12 22:59:59 | 10 | 2020 | 10 |  |
| 1307 | 2020-06-24 23:00:00 | 2022-10-12 22:59:59 | 10 | 2020 | 11 |  |
| 1307 | 2020-06-24 23:00:00 | 2022-10-12 22:59:59 | 10 | 2020 | 12 |  |
| 1307 | 2020-06-24 23:00:00 | 2022-10-12 22:59:59 | 10 | 2020 | 1 |  |
| 1307 | 2020-06-24 23:00:00 | 2022-10-12 22:59:59 | 10 | 2020 | 2 |  |
| 1307 | 2020-06-24 23:00:00 | 2022-10-12 22:59:59 | 10 | 2020 | 3 |  |

sep_year for the last 3 records should be 2021 but not 2020.

Any suggestion will be extremely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're attempting to create new row(s) for each record in `table_1`. Each new row would represent a unique month/year that falls in between `start_date` and `mod_end_date`.

One way to do this could be to create an array of the # of months that should be added to `start_date` using `range()` and `dateDiff`, use `arrayJoin` as you did to create a new row for each element of the array, then use `addMonths` to create the incremental dates in between the start/end dates. Finally, you could use `toMonth()` and `toYear()` to extract the month and year of the incremental date:

```
WITH
    toDateTime('2020-06-24 23:00:00') AS start,
    toDateTime('2022-10-12 22:59:59') AS "end",
    dateDiff('month', start, "end") AS steps
SELECT
    start, "end",
    arrayJoin(range(1, steps)) AS months,
    addMonths(start, months) AS intermediate,
    toYear(intermediate) AS sep_year,
    toMonth(intermediate) AS sep_month
```

This yields:

| Start | End | Months | Intermediate | Sep_Year | Sep_Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-06-24T23:00:00 | 2022-10-12T22:59:59 | 1 | 2020-07-24T23:00:00 | 2020 | 7 |
| 2020-06-24T23:00:00 | 2022-10-12T22:59:59 | 2 | 2020-08-24T23:00:00 | 2020 | 8 |
| 2020-06-24T23:00:00 | 2022-10-12T22:59:59 | 3 | 2020-09-24T23:00:00 | 2020 | 9 |
| 2020-06-24T23:00:00 | 2022-10-12T22:59:59 | 4 | 2020-10-24T23:00:00 | 2020 | 10 |
| 2020-06-24T23:00:00 | 2022-10-12T22:59:59 | 5 | 2020-11-24T23:00:00 | 2020 | 11 |
| 2020-06-24T23:00:00 | 2022-10-12T22:59:59 | 6 | 2020-12-24T23:00:00 | 2020 | 12 |
| 2020-06-24T23:00:00 | 2022-10-12T22:59:59 | 7 | 2021-01-24T23:00:00 | 2021 | 1 |
| 2020-06-24T23:00:00 | 2022-10-12T22:59:59 | 8 | 2021-02-24T23:00:00 | 2021 | 2 |
| 2020-06-24T23:00:00 | 2022-10-12T22:59:59 | 9 | 2021-03-24T23:00:00 | 2021 | 3 |
| 2020-06-24T23:00:00 | 2022-10-12T22:59:59 | 10 | 2021-04-24T23:00:00 | 2021 | 4 |
| 2020-06-24T23:00:00 | 2022-10-12T22:59:59 | 11 | 2021-05-24T23:00:00 | 2021 | 5 |
| 2020-06-24T23:00:00 | 2022-10-12T22:59:59 | 12 | 2021-06-24T23:00:00 | 2021 | 6 |
| 2020-06-24T23:00:00 | 2022-10-12T22:59:59 | 13 | 2021-07-24T23:00:00 | 2021 | 7 |
| 2020-06-24T23:00:00 | 2022-10-12T22:59:59 | 14 | 2021-08-24T23:00:00 | 2021 | 8 |
| 2020-06-24T23:00:00 | 2022-10-12T22:59:59 | 15 | 2021-09-24T23:00:00 | 2021 | 9 |

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).